# Unable to switch to PERL perspective in Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 on Windows 10 with EPIC 0.7.2

Tags: eclipse, perl, perspective, epic

I am trying to use Eclipse IDE (Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 on Windows 10) to codding with PERL. But unable to switch perspective to Perl by reason of there is no Perl link in "Open Perspective" window:
[image]

I installed EPIC. This screenshot tell us is that EPIC version 0.7.2 was installed:
[image]

But I unable to switch perspective by reason of there is no Perl entry in "Open Perspective" window (see screenshot above). What am I doing wrong how to switch perspective to Perl and create Perl project. Thanks.